# hibernate validation return different status code for different scenarios for the same constraint violation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, validation, java-8, hibernate-validator

I've added a custom annotation using Hibernate for checking a valid digital signature.

Custom annotation :- `@ValidDigitalSignature`

I have two requirements stated below :-

- Case 1 :- Return HTTP status code 404 Not Found when there is a non matching digital signature in the incoming request.
- Case 2 :- Return HTTP status code 400 Bad Request when there is an extra character in the incoming request digital signature.

There can be a argument stating that Case 2 is a subset of Case 1. But there are other scenarios similar to the ones mentioned above.

Currently I return HTTP status code 400 for both the scenarios mentioned above.

Is there a way that I can conditionally return different status codes based on the above mentioned requirement? Any help would be useful

Constraint :

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DigitalSignatureValidator.class)
public @interface ValidDigitalSignature {

    String message() default "{signature does not match}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Comment: Can you share your custom annotations

Comment: Share validator class also